# How to Record and Print messages in DITA-OT logs?

Tags: xslt-2.0, dita-ot

I have created a custom plugin in DITA-OT 3.4 named com.myorg.dita.html5, which is an extension of the base plugin org.dita.html5. The plugin is set up correctly and functioning as expected.

In the main custom XSLT file of this plugin, I process each topic by matching the root node using <xsl:template match="/">. There are other XSLTs in plugin to apply relavant customizations.

My Current challenge is; I need to find all the elements that has `class=topic/xref` that has `<data>`  element as child or descendant and does not have any value in @value attribute. I need to record all such instances during the entire dita-ot process. If any error recorded then print it and terminate the dita-ot process. I need to do this in this XSL if possible.

My Original xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <!-- root rule -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'm trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="xs exsl" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="errorLog" as="element()*"/>
    <!-- root rule -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(@class, ' topic/xref ')]" mode="test"/>
        <xsl:if test="$errorLog">
            <!-- Print the errors -->
            <xsl:message terminate="Yes">
                <xsl:text>List of all the errors </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$errorLog"/>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, 'topic/xref')]" mode="test">
        <xsl:if test="exists(//data) and not(//data/@value ='')">
            <!-- Append the error to the errorLog variable -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:sequence select="$errorLog, current()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you spend some time learning the fundamentals of xslt, xpath and  how variables are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds as if an XSLT 3.0 accumulator could help. XSLT 2 and DITA-OT are usually run with Saxon, the currently supported versions of Saxon are 10, 11, 12, which are all XSLT 3.0 processors anyway and just support XSLT 2 stylesheets through backwards compatibility.

So you could try e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="xs exsl" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="errorLog" as="element()*" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*[contains(@class, 'topic/xref')][exists(//data) and not(//data/@value ='')]" select="$value, ."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <!-- root rule -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(@class, ' topic/xref ')]" mode="test"/>
        <xsl:if test="accumulator-after('errorLog')">
            <!-- Print the errors -->
            <xsl:message terminate="Yes">
                <xsl:text>List of all the errors </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="accumulator-after('errorLog')"/>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="test" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="errorLog"/>

    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="errorLog"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have used the conditions from your original code in the accumulator rule with e.g.

```
<xsl:accumulator name="errorLog" as="element()*" initial-value="()">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*[contains(@class, 'topic/xref')][exists(//data) and not(//data/@value ='')]" select="$value, ."/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

but I suspect you rather want

```
<xsl:accumulator name="errorLog" as="element()*" initial-value="()">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*[contains(@class, 'topic/xref')][exists(.//data) and not(.//data/@value ='')]" select="$value, ."/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'm using Saxon HE--9.9-4. Using above code the build is failing with an exception `\build_myplugin-html5.xml:36: net.sf.saxon.trans.UncheckedXPathException: Accumulator errorLog is not applicable to the current document
 at net.sf.saxon.lib.DelegatingErrorListener.fatalError(DelegatingErrorListener.java:51)`. I looked at your answer in another post related to this error [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263042/accumulator-is-not-applicable-to-the-current-document-with-saxon-pe-9-9-1-5-java) but I see the mode is already included in the code.

Comment: any suggestion to resolve this? @MartinHonnen

Comment: @user19732805, see whether adding `use-accumulators="errorLog"` to the `xsl:mode` declaration helps

Comment: @user19732805, it might be necessary to add `<xsl:mode use-accumulators="errorLog"/>` for the unnamed mode.

Comment: It dint help, unfortunatly.

Comment: @user19732805, based on a test with a simpler sample and some rereading of the accumulator section in the XSLT 3.0 spec I think that `<xsl:mode use-accumulators="errorLog"/>` should help. Did you try that? If that doesn't help then we need to identify which is the default mode in your setup/configuration.

Comment: sorry, I was too fast in responding. After adding `<xsl:mode use-accumulators="errorLog"/>` statement, it worked. Thank you so much.